# StorageDevice.FromId throwing "Not Implemented Exception" on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, windowsiot, dragonboard

I am developing a customer specific application using Windows 10 IoT on a DragonBoard 410c.
In this application it is essential to know which drive is the SD card and which one is an additional USB stick. I used to handle this through the drive letters using

```
KnownFolders.RemovableDevices
```

since the SD card is supposed to have the drive letter "D".
On one board, though, the SD card suddenly had the drive letter "E" and my code failed.

Therefore I started using

```
var deviceInfos = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync( DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice );
```

to enumerate the removable drives and then searching the `Id` string of every `DeviceInformation` object for a specific pattern:

```
private StorageFolder _sdCard;
private StorageFolder _usbDrive;

foreach( DeviceInformation info in deviceInfos )
{
    string id = info.Id.ToUpper();

    try
    {

        if( id.Contains( SDId ) )
        {                            
            _sdCard = StorageDevice.FromId( info.Id );
        }
        else if( id.Contains( USBId ) )
        {
            _usbDrive = StorageDevice.FromId( info.Id );
        }

    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine( "########## Error " + e );
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, `StorageDevice.FromId()` throws `NotImplementedException`.

I've enabled the capability for removable storage as well as file type associations in the `.appxmanifest`. I do not have any problems accessing files on any removable storage device. Did anyone experience a similar problem and find a solution for it? Does anyone have a different idea of reliably retrieving a `StorageFolder` for the SD Card if additional USB sticks might be attached?

Comment: Sorry, I missed an await in the DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync. It's in my code, though, and not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just after finishing the question I have found a solution myself, although I am not too happy with it. Using

```
StorageFolder                removableDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> drives           = await removableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
```

the first element in drives always represents the SD Card, this is also stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card

But I do not think this is a very reliable solution and I am still looking for something else.

Comment: You can check its `DisplayName`. For more information, reference [this](https://blog.falafel.com/readwrite-data-fromto-usb-thumb-drive-windows-iot-core-device/).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The display name shows the volume's name, which is completely unknown. In the example mentioned the name of the volume was supposingly set to "USB DRIVE".